# Checking number of messages in jms queue code

Tags: java, queue, jms

I need to check number of messages in a jms queue for that i am using queuebrowser.
Actually i have 2 queues. I check if there are more then 10 messages in second queue then the first queue should not send messages to the second queue.

This is my code snippet

```
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

            Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup(inputQueue); // this is the first queue (named iniputQueue)

            session = connection.createSession();

                consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

            // change code for browsing queue
            Queue senderqueue = (Queue) initialContext
                    .lookup(senderQueue);
            QueueBrowser queueBrowser = session.createBrowser(senderqueue); //this is second queue named senderQueue

            connection.start();
//by queuebrowser i check if messages in second queue is more then 10 then do  //not send the message
            Enumeration e = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
            int numMsgs=0;
            // count number of messages
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                numMsgs++;
                if(numMsgs>10){
                    checkFlag=false;
                    break;
                }else{
                    checkFlag=true;
                }
            }

            LOG.debug("checkflag is" +checkFlag);

            if (checkFlag) {

                ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) consumer
                        .receive(1);

                if (objectMessage != null) {
                    objectMessage.acknowledge();
                    //
                    LOG.debug("sending one batch out");
                    InputJSON inputJson = (InputJSON) objectMessage
                            .getObject();

                    SendService messageService = new SendService();

                    messageService.processInputFromQueue(inputJson);


                }



            }
```

the above code is called by a schedular every 2 secs which keeps checking the sender queue and based on that sends message out from input queue.

Is there any better way to do this..